# Return boolean if postgresql match is found

Tags: sql, postgresql, loops, procedure

I am a beginner when it comes to databases. I would like to return true in postgresql if there is a player in my players table with is_active set to true and return false otherwise. Should I use a procedure or function for this ? I tried did this with simple select but i guess its not good idea.
How should it look like ?

````
CREATE TABLE player (
    user_id INT8 PRIMARY KEY,
    is_active BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a function or a loop:

```
select exists (select * 
               from player
               where is_active)
```